# Double vertical spacing : how to fix this?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

Consider the following :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcommand*\squared[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=rectangle, draw, inner color = white, drop shadow = {opaque, black}, inner sep=3pt, text justified] (char) {#1};}}

\newtheoremstyle{exercise}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {\hangindent=2em}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  {.8em}
  {\squared{\thmnumber{#2}}}

\theoremstyle{exercise}
\newtheorem{exercise}{}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{r @{\hskip .4em} X}
        a) & This is a test. \\
        b) & I say
        $$
            \pi \approx 3.14.
        $$ \\
        c) & Do you agree?
    \end{tabularx}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

It seems like the fact that b) finishes with math mode adds extra vertical spacing before c). But I would like the spacing to be uniform. That is, I want the same vertical space before b) and before c). How to do it ?

Comment: off topic: don't use `$$ $$`. Use `\[ \]` instead.

Comment: @Sigur Why ? I've always used `$$ $$` and it has never done anything bad up to this date.

Comment: see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: Use an optional argument to line break after the math: `\[ \pi \approx 3.14 \] \\[-1.75\belowdisplayskip]`

Comment: I don't know what is the exactly value used in line breaks. My suggestion looks nice but note that you are using another value to `\arraystretch` so I used `1.75`.

Answer (score 3):

You have few options.

First one is to add the equation in a row of its own:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcommand*\squared[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=rectangle, draw, inner color = white, drop shadow = {opaque, black}, inner sep=3pt, text justified] (char) {#1};}}

\newtheoremstyle{exercise}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {\hangindent=2em}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  {.8em}
  {\squared{\thmnumber{#2}}}

\theoremstyle{exercise}
\newtheorem{exercise}{}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{r @{\hskip .4em} X}
        a) & This is a test. \\
        b) & I say \\
           &
            \hfil $\pi \approx 3.14$.
            \\
        c) & Do you agree?
    \end{tabularx}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I feel that a list enumerate would be the better way to go after some modifications to the exercise environment.

Here is some more additions. These are not perfect as the `\arraystretch` is modified and the widths of `\parbox` and `\minipage` are not accurately calculated. Nevertheless, it may serve as a starting point.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcommand*\squared[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=rectangle, draw, inner color = white, drop shadow = {opaque, black}, inner sep=3pt, text justified] (char) {#1};}}

\newtheoremstyle{exercise}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {\hangindent=2em}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  {.8em}
  {\squared{\thmnumber{#2}}}

\theoremstyle{exercise}
\newtheorem{exercise}{}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\usepackage{tabularx,enumitem,showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
    \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2.8em\relax}[t]{@{\,}r @{\hskip .4em} X}
        a) & This is a test. \\
        b) & I say \parbox[t]{0.88\linewidth}{%
           \[
            π\approx 3.14.
           \]
           }\\
        c) & Do you agree?
    \end{tabularx}
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.928\linewidth}
     \begin{enumerate}[label = \alph*),leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
        \item This is a test.
        \item I say
           \[
            π\approx 3.14.
            \]
        \item Do you agree?
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So simple and clear.

Comment: @HarishKumar But then the spacing before the math mode will be that of the array, which may differ from other parts of the text not in an array ?

Comment: @Amateur True, but you want same spacing. As a remedy, try enclosing the equation inside a `\parbox` and use `\[...\]`

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks for the idea. I've also tried to use a list enumerate, as you suggested. But the `\hangindent` won't work on the list. Is that why you say "after some modifications to the exercise environment" ?